# Как можно исправить?

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void inptA (int **A, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    int m = 3;   
    int **A = new int *[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new int [m];
    }
    intpA (A, n, m);
    return 0;
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:82:19: error: ‘intpA’ was not declared in this scope
     intpA (A, n, m);
```

Answer (score 3):

Это обычная опечатка в имени переменной.

Вы объявили функцию с именем `inptA`, а в обращении к ней используете имя `intpA`.

Причина этой ошибки состоит в том, что вы без причины используете сокращенную форму от слова `input`  для именования функции.

Было бы значительно лучше, если бы вы использовали не сокращенное слово `input` в именовании функции:

```
void inputA (int **A, int n, int m)
```

В этом случае ваш код был бы более читабельным и ясным, и позволял бы избежать подобного рода опечаток.

Answer (score 2):

Внимательнее надо быть. Функция у вас названа in**pt**A, а вызываете вы in**tp**A.